# Storing a big sparse matrix in memory to compute eigenvalues

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sparse-matrix

For my case it's 40000*40000 elements and I only need this matrix to count the eigenvalues.

My problem is how to store the matrix in memory, so I can find the eigenvalues. Here are the details about the matrix:

```
A=np.array([((Nx-2)(Nz-2))[1/4],((Nx-2)(Nz-2))[1/2],((Nx-2)(Nz-2))[2],((Nx-2)(Nz-2))[1/2],((Nx-2)(Nz-2))[1/4]])
diags=np.array([-Nx,-1,0,1,Nx])
M=spdiags(A, diags, (Nx-2)(Nz-2), (Nx-2)(Nz-2)).toarray()
alpha=np.linalg.eigvals(M)
```

Error

```
File "C:/Users/mr_lu/Downloads/2d.py", line 106, in <module>
  M=spdiags(A, diags, (Nx-2)*(Nz-2), (Nx-2)*(Nz-2)).toarray()
File "C:\Users\mr_lu\PycharmProjects\2d\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 878, in toarray
  return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray(order=order, out=out)
File "C:\Users\mr_lu\PycharmProjects\2d\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 310, in toarray
  B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
File "C:\Users\mr_lu\PycharmProjects\2d\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 1184, in _process_toarray_args
  return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Comment: What's a typical value of `Nx`, `Nz`?  Does your code run for smaller values?  As posted your code doesn't work, at least not with scalar values: `(Nx-2)(Nz-2))` gives a `callable` error.

Comment: Does `M = spdiags(...)`, without the `toarray()` work?  The `toarray()` converts a sparse matrix to dense.  So even if the sparse matrix exists, the dense array could very well take up to much memory.  You'll need to use `sparse` eigenvalues methods if the full dense array is too large.

Comment: Yes it runs for smaller values, Nx and Nz can get until the value 100 as maximum but for bigger values the error shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important details of working with sparse matrices is to never use dense matrix intermediates! It seems that the memory problem occurs when you call `toarray()`. This is because you are converting a `scipy.sparse` matrix into a dense `numpy.array`. Instead of using the `numpy` module for calculating the eigenvalues on the dense matrix, try using the `scipy.sparse.linalg` function `eigs` to find the eigenvalues of your sparse matrix.